# Getting value from Bottom-Up method

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables named 'Purchase' and 'ClosingStock'

Sample tables in dbfiddle is attached for quick actions.

**Table: Purchase Table**

```
+----------+--------------+-----+-----------+
| ItemName | PurchaseDate | QTY | CostPrice |
+----------+--------------+-----+-----------+
| ItemA    | 2022-03-14   |  20 | 32.00     |
| ItemA    | 2022-04-28   |   7 | 30.00     |
| ItemA    | 2022-06-17   |  33 | 25.00     |
|          |              |     |           |
| ItemB    | 2022-05-16   |  65 | 50.00     |
+----------+--------------+-----+-----------+
```

**Table: ClosingStock**

```
+----------+--------------+
| ItemName | ClosingStock |
+----------+--------------+
| ItemA    |           35 |
| ItemB    |           60 |
+----------+--------------+
```

**Required Result**

```
+----------+--------------+------------+
| ItemName | ClosingStock | TotalValue |
+----------+--------------+------------+
| ItemA    |           35 |        885 |
| ItemB    |           60 |       3000 |
+----------+--------------+------------+
```

The required query should return the 'TotalValue' based on bottom-up method

for example:

In my sample dataset, ItemA has ClosingQTY = 35

To calculate TotalValue for ItemA, it should check the last record in Purchase table (QTY column).
Here it is 33.

So out of 35 ClosingQTY,  33 pieces would have value (33 * 25).
For the remaining 2 qty of ItemA, it should look for 2nd last record in Purchase.
So it would be (2 * 30).

Math would be (33 * 25) + (2 * 30) = 885

So for total 35 qty of ItemA, TotalValue would be 885.
similar calculation for ItemB and so on.

https://dbfiddle.uk/plwwAGr6

Comment: `select ItemName, ClosingQTY, sum(case when rt <= ClosingQTY then QTY else ClosingQTY - (rt-QTY) end *CostPrice)
from
(
select c.ClosingQTY, p.*, sum(p.QTY) over(partition by p.ItemName order by p.PurchaseDate desc rows unbounded preceding) as rt
from ClosingStock as c
join Purchase as p on c.ItemName = p.ItemName
) as r
where rt-QTY < ClosingQTY
group by ItemName, ClosingQTY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both solutions work (by IPTR and astentx)

It seems method by IPTS more efficient as it uses "unbounded preceding"

```
select ItemName, ClosingQTY
  ,sum(case when rt <= ClosingQTY then QTY else ClosingQTY - (rt - QTY) end * CostPrice) 
from 
  (
    select 
      c.ClosingQTY, 
      p.*, 
      sum(p.QTY) over(partition by p.ItemName order by p.PurchaseDate desc rows unbounded preceding) as rt 
    from 
      ClosingStock as c 
      join Purchase as p on c.ItemName = p.ItemName
  ) as r 
where rt - QTY < ClosingQTY 
group by ItemName, ClosingQTY
```

Comment: *more efficient as it uses "unbounded preceding"* - it is not clear why and how it affects efficiency, because this is a default window frame if `order by` is specified: [*If ROWS/RANGE is not specified but ORDER BY is specified, RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW is used as default for window frame*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks). Both queries are the same except that Iptr's solution uses subquery and filters it by `where` clause instead of setting the value to zero inside `case` expression.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `join`, calculate running sum of `QTY`, compare it with `ClosingStock` and take only a part from `QTY` when running sum becomes greater than `ClosingStock`. Then aggregate calculated quantity multiplied by a price.

```
with purchase(ItemName, PurchaseDate, QTY, CostPrice) as (
  select 'ItemA', convert(date, '2022-03-14'), 20, 32.00 union all
  select 'ItemA', convert(date, '2022-04-28'),  7, 30.00 union all
  select 'ItemA', convert(date, '2022-06-17'), 33, 25.00 union all
  select 'ItemB', convert(date, '2022-05-16'), 65, 50.00
)
, stock(ItemName, ClosingStock) as (
  select 'ItemA', 35 union all
  select 'ItemB', 60
)
select
  itemname
  , sum(TotalValue ) as TotalValue
from (
  select
    p.itemname
    , case
        /*Running total is less than stock - take purchase in full*/
        when s.ClosingStock
          >= sum(p.qty) over(
               partition by p.itemname order by PurchaseDate desc
             )
        then p.qty
        /*Otherwise if previous running total is less then stock - take only part*/
        when s.ClosingStock - (
          sum(p.qty) over(
            partition by p.itemname order by PurchaseDate desc
          ) - p.qty
        ) > 0
        then s.ClosingStock - (sum(p.qty) over(partition by p.itemname order by PurchaseDate desc) - p.qty)
        /*When previous running total is greater than stock, then do not account this purchase*/
    end * p.costprice as TotalValue 
    , p.purchasedate
    , s.closingstock
  from purchase as p
    join stock as s
    on p.ItemName = s.ItemName
) as t
group by itemname
```

| itemname | TotalValue |
| --- | --- |
| ItemA | 885.00 |
| ItemB | 3000.00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sRSkdRyg)